# How to remove checked star on jQuery Star Rating plugin?

Tags: jquery, html

I've been using this plugin for quit a time and everybody love it. Extra credit to the developer!! However, just now I need to separate the form into a few section, so jQuery show() and hide() came to a rescue. I show/hide using a button with id #next. Ok here is the scenario:

Section 1 > Section 2 > Section 3

On Section 2, there is a split question e.g answering A will show Section 3a or answering B will show Section 3b. Both Section 3a and 3b are using the jQuery Star Rating plugin. I've a back button on Section 2 so that user can change their answer on section 1 and continue fill the form.

The problem is, if I choose to answer A on section 2, then proceed to Section 3a and rate it 4, it's fine. But if I clicked back to Section 2 and change my answer to  B, I proceed to Section 3b, but the value from Section 3a still submitted, which is holding value 4 from my previous click.

So, how do I solve this?

Comment: @Jordan here is the page, hopefully it could help
[link](http://www.apadmedia.com/star-rating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about [this plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/). The API says that

```
$('.my-class').rating('drain');
```

will clear your stars.

Comment: I've try but it just not working. try to see the live page at [link](http://www.apadmedia.com/star-rating/)

Comment: thanks! it's works actually. I've called a wrong class previously. Thanks a lot! Also thanks Firebug :p